# Getting certificate error while clicking on an installed certificate using HTTP (s) Script Recorder

Tags: certificate, jmeter

I have downloaded `jMeter 2.11` and getting following certificate error while clicking on Start Button to record using `HTTP (s) Script Recorder`. However, I have installed the certificate. Could you please let me know how do I resolve this?

> Root CA certificate: apachejmetertemporaryrootCA created in JMeter bin
>   directory You can install it following instructions in component
>   reference documentation (see installing the jmeter CA Certificate for
>   HTTPs recording paragraph) Please check the details below when
>   installing the certificate in the browser CN=_DO NOT INSTALL unless
>   this is your certificate (jmeter root CA) OU=username:XXXXXXXXX, C=US
>   Fingerprint(SHA1):XXXXXXXXX Created:XXXXX

Answer (score 0):

This is not error. 
This is status message from JMeter, that it has finished creating the required certificate to use during using of JMeter proxy server.
Follow: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder